# Is it a generalization?

Tags: meaning, etymology, verbs, nouns

According to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/abhor) the verb *abhor* carries a moral connotation (at least), indicating a strong feeling of detesting something **on moral grounds**:

> **abhor**: to hate a way of behaving or thinking, often because you think it is not moral:
>
> - *I abhor all forms of racism.*

However, I've noticed that the related noun *abhorrence* does not usually have the same degree of association with morality. Typical sentences showing this are:

- He has an *abhorrence* of monkeys.
- Most people have an *abhorrence* of snakes.
- Many people show *abhorrence* of spiders.

And [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/abhorrence) doesn't add the rider about morality:

> **abhorrence**: a feeling of hating something or someone: ...
>
> - *She has an abhorrence of change.* ...
> - The writer reviews the effect of this blunt abhorrence of abnormal forms ...

[Though to be fair, 90% of the example sentences given do involve a moral revulsion.]

Looking back at the animal examples: at first glance, there aren't specific reasons to detest these animals for moral reasons. But I considered the possibility that covert (or perhaps projected) moral qualities could be involved. For instance, spiders are hematocryal ... although that might sound quite far-fetched.

So can anyone support this theory of broadening? And can anyone offer an explanation for the difference in degree of association with moral judgements associated with *abhor* and *abhorrence*?

If necessary, you could involve etymological accounts.

Comment: I think the premise of your question is wrong. The dictionary definitions of *abhor* don't say that it is used exclusively for detesting something morally.

Comment: [to hate a way of behaving or thinking, often because you think it is not moral][1]


  [1]:https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/abhor

Comment: There's the word *often* in that definition; it's not actually *wrong* to say "I abhor snakes." And take a look at this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=abhorrence+of+snakes%2C+abhor+snakes%2Cabhorrence+of+slavery%2Cabhor+slavery&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10); people have an *abhorrence of slavery* a lot more often than they have an *abhorrence of snakes*.

Comment: @PeterShor: But as [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+abhor+snakes%2CI+abhor+slavery%2CI+detest+snakes%2CI+detest+slavery&year_start=1910&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=20) shows, a century ago people nearly always said ***I abhor slavery***, whereas today they're just as likely to say ***I detest slavery*** (apparently we always detested rather than abhorred snakes, though). Bottom line: ***to abhor*** is falling out of fashion in modern English.

Comment: See [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abhorrence): "abhorrence" can mean "abhorring" but can be used in a weaker sense "strong repugnance or disgust". This isn't too unusual. If you look in the OED I'm sure you can get more detail on how usage has changed.

Comment: Yes, Cambridge backs up your claim, adding the 'often because you think it is not moral' rider in the definition of the verb, but omitting it in the definition of the noun. I'd say the DVs and closure are harsh (though it would have been better if you'd quoted the CD definitions in the question itself). The question is at root a good one, but, I'd wager, difficult to give a convincing answer to. Related words in different word classes quite often have divergent senses or at least associations (a telescope / to telescope; a commendable scheme / ??a commendable schemer ...).

Comment: As for the other question: 'an abhorrence of abnormal forms [scary shapes]' is an example not easily interpreted in terms of morality. If one delves deeper into psycholinguistics here, one gets outside the ELU remit.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for the edits and your comments. I'm wondering, though, where I can get hints on this kind of meaning broadening, as you mentioned it's a bit off topic for ELU. Like some books or forums to browse?

Comment: "I abhor snakes" and "I have an abhorrence of snakes" sound wrong to me. I would find that usage exceedingly strange, though other people in this thread seem to disagree.

Comment: I'd ask a question (or perhaps a couple of questions) on ELU Meta (requests for resources are welcome there). One about general works on semantic shift / broadening, and one about works on psycholinguistics in the English language, with special reference to semantic shifts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addressing your speculation that *abhorrence* was generalized, it appears that the opposite occurred and that *abhor* was specialized.

Looking in the OED, the original meaning (from the OED) was the same as the Latin word *abhorrere:*

> **abhor:** To shrink with horror or repugnance from; to recoil from. *Obsolete.*

From the citations in the OED, it looks like what happened is that *abhor*'s meaning narrowed to mean "detest on moral grounds", rather than *abhorrence*'s meaning broadening to include cases when the grounds for abhorrence were not moral ones.

Here are some of the uses of *abhor* from the OED, chosen from recent enough citations that they are comprehensible, but from long enough ago that the meaning had not yet narrowed; I believe these show that *abhor* originally wasn't mainly used for immoral things (although of course, sometimes it was).

> a1522   G. Douglas tr. Virgil *Æneid* (1960) xiii. x. 47   Abhor thou nocht the fyre and flambis brycht,
>
> 1555   W. Waterman tr. J. Boemus *Fardle of Facions* ii. x. 216   This people so despiseth al other men,..that thei abhor to speake to theim.
>
> 1576   T. Rogers *Philos. Disc. Anat. Minde* ii. xlv. f. 197v   Ingratitude, a vice of all other moste to be abhorred.
>
> a1616   W. Shakespeare *Twelfth Night* (1623) ii. v. 193   Hee will come to her in yellow stockings, and 'tis a colour she abhorres.
>
> a1616   W. Shakespeare *Othello* (1623) iv. ii. 166   I cannot say Whore, It do's abhorre me now I speake the word.
>
> 1617   F. *Moryson Itinerary* i. iii. i. 208   Most part of the Marriners are Greekes, the Italians abhorring from being sea men.
>
> 1678 J. P. tr. J. Johnstone *Descr. Nature Four-footed Beasts* iii. i. 63/1   The creaking of wheels frights him. A bright table-cloath drives him away. He abhors fire, and dares not come neare it.

Your other question was: why is *abhorrence* used for non-immoral things more often than *abhor*? Possibly it has to do with a lack of synonyms for *abhorrence*.

Here are some synonyms for *detest/abhor* and the associated nouns. (The asterisks indicate words that, although they are in the dictionary, are very rarely used.)

> I abhor snakes.
> I have an abhorrence of snakes.
>
> I loathe snakes.
> I have a loathing of snakes.
>
> I detest snakes.
> *I have a detestation of snakes.
>
> I despise snakes.
> *I have a despisal of snakes.

So possibly somebody trying to turn *detest* into a noun may not think of *loathing*, and may use *abhorrence* instead.

Finally, I want to add that I think *abhorrence* carries a connotation of immorality as well, although maybe not as strong a one as *abhor*. [This Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=abhorrence+of+snakes%2Cloathing+of+snakes%2Cabhorrence+of+falsehood%2Cloathing+of+falsehood&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) shows that people are more likely to have *an abhorrence of falsehood*, but more likely to have *a loathing of snakes*.

Comment: But what is the certain reason why the meaning of abhor is narrowed down to "detest on moral grounds"?

Comment: @ThomasPeng: Except in very rare cases, we can never figure out the "reason" for a change in how words are used. Nobody decided to change the connotations of *abhor*; it just happened.

Comment: ... One possibility is that someone in the public eye used a word to apply to a subset of all possible relevant referents, and the use with this association took off, with a strengthening level of connotation

Answer (score 0):

> According to Cambridge Dictionary the verb abhor carries a moral connotation (at least), indicating a strong feeling of detesting something on moral grounds:

It is not even a generalisation: it is wrong because it is incomplete.

A better statement would be

> **In certain contexts,** according to Cambridge Dictionary the verb abhor carries a moral connotation (at least), indicating a strong feeling of detesting something on moral grounds:
>
> **Abhor** relates to morals *when morals are the context.*

I abhor vinegar. I really cannot stand it.

Can you see any morality in vinegar?

OED (which does not mention morals)

> **2. To regard with disgust or hatred; to loathe, abominate. Now frequently in hyperbolic use.**
>
> **a. transitive.**
>
> 1959   R. Lardner Best Short Stories III. 51   *He absolutely abhors
> visiting and thinks there ought to be a law against invitations that
> go beyond dinner and bridge.*
>
> 1999   Antique Dealer & Collectors Guide Apr. 41/1   *One either
> abhors or adores the paintings with their primary colour and thick
> black outlines.*
>
> 1920   E. H. Porter Mary Marie iii. 32   *‘Oh, yes, my little maid’
> (above all things I abhor to be called a little maid!) one of them
> cried.*

These uses are indistinguishable from those with a moral content:

> 2004   D. Fletcher Dark Warrior xxviii. 273   *As much as it abhorred
> her, she would have no choice but to be intimate with Decimus as soon
> as possible.*

Comment: The fact is that we never use 'I abhor vinegar':[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=abhor+vinegar&year_start=1500&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: @ThomasPeng - I am unsure who you think "we" refers to - do you mean "non-native speakers?" I would remind you that absence of evidence is not evidence of absence. You really need to understand how English and Ngrams works. You will see that there is no result in Ngrams for "I abhor usury/infidelity" so what does that show?